# Find the area of the region bounded by two curves

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find the area of the region that is bounded by $y=x^2-4$ and $y=2x-1$

I think I solved it, but I don't know what the right answer is so I'm not sure!

I got:

$$da = wl$$
$$=(x^2-4)-(2x-1)dy$$
$$=(x^2-2x-3)dy$$
$$\int{}da = \int{(x^2-2x-3)dy}$$
$$a = \frac{x^3}{3}-x^2-3x+c$$

Comment: Is your first function supposed to be $y=x^2-4$? And note that area is a number, not an expression here. You need limits on the integral. I would suggest drawing the graphs of your functions first.

Comment: yes it was! How did you know haha?  And sorry about that.  And I did graph it first, I just didn't know you could get that cool graph thing on here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it you mean $y=x^2-4$ and $y=2x-1$.

**Draw a picture**.  We get a familiar parabola, and a straight line.  The straight line $y=2x-1$ meets the parabola where $x^2-4=2x-1$. This can be rearranged to $x^2-2x-3=0$. The quadratic factors as $(x-3)(x+1)$, so the meeting points are at $x=-1$ and $x=3$.

Note that the finite region caught between the two has the line *above* the curve. Thus our area is
$$\int_{-1}^3\left((2x-1)-(x^2-4)\right)\,dx.$$
Before integrating, simplify the integrand a bit.